# Crash al asignar RenderTransform con ScaleTransform en win7 y algunas instalaciones de win10

Tags: .net, windows, wpf, windows10

Crash al asignar RenderTransform con ScaleTransform en win7 y algunas instalaciones de win10

```
this.RenderTransform = scaladoDePantalla; en constructor.

public Clientes(Window mainWindow, ScaleTransform scaladoDePantalla, List<Object> _listaDeClientes){
        this.Owner = mainWindow;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        try
            {
            this.RenderTransform = scaladoDePantalla;
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

...

En Windows 10 de desarrollo funciona perfecto, sin problemas.
Pero crashea en otras instalaciones de Windows 10 y en un VBox de Windows 7

Usando .NET 4.6.1

El tema del try ayuda a que la aplicación no crashee, pero no redimensiona la Window

Pasa cuando cliente esta en un dll que acompaña. Es de destacar que no pasa, no falla, en la maquina de desarrollo un I7 con Windows 10.

Esta metodología la uso para escalar todo de acuerdo a la rtesolucion de pantalla en la que se ejecuta la aplicación.

Gracias anticipadamente...

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía ese problema cuando incluía referencias a Aero, el cual viene con Windows 7, especificamente cuando usaba un Style personalizado para los Combobox, el cual empezaba así:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
```

Lo que hice para salir del paso es no aplicar el style, pero en si, el problema era la linea que referenciaba al Aero:

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2
```

Ya que Windows 10 no tiene Aero pero Windows 7 si, se me caía en uno y en el otro no. El componente es la referencia a PresentationFramework.

Como no profundizas más en el código no se que cosas incluye pero fíjate en ese tipo de referencias que son específicas de algunas versiones y causan estos problemas difíciles de resolver cuando no has tenido la experiencia.

Un saludo.